# f:param or f:attribute support on primefaces autocomplete?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've read that the core JSF components support the **f:param** and **f:attribute** tag, in order to pass some values to the serverside for the enclosing UI Components.

There's a need for me to be able to do this for primefaces' autocomplete component,
so that the autocomplete method will be able to make use of the parameter supplied by the **f:param** or **f:attribute**.
I tried finding out ways to accomplish this, and found out that the complete method parameter is fixed and cannot take more arguments,
hence im thinking of using **f:param** or **f:attribute**.

Im use the 2.2.x version, and based on my experiment, i cant seem to get the **f:param** or the **f:attribute** working

```
<p:autocomplete ...>
   <f:param name="myParam" value="xxxx" />
</p:autocomplete>
```

Is primefaces going to support this feature on the autocomplete component ?
Is there anyway i can find out which tags that support the parameters and those who dont ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally i got it working !

Here's the jsf part :

```
<p:autoComplete id="#{cc.attrs.id}" label="#{cc.attrs.label}"
    ....
    completeMethod="#{filterableRaceAutocompleteBean.filterRace}">

    <f:attribute name="filter" value="#{cc.attrs.filter}" />

</p:autoComplete>
```

And here is the source :

```
public List<Dto> filterRace(String filterString) {
    String filterValue = (String) UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getAttributes().get("filter");
    log.debug("filter string : " + filterString + ", with query filter of : " + filterValue);

    ....

    return result;
}
```

Comment: nice thing dude :D ... helped me got rid of ActionEvent.

Comment: Nice, but your attribute name MUST be no "param", I suspect p:autocomplete uses a "param" attribute internally. So use whatever name but "param".