# f:param not passed in ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
<h:inputHidden value="autoCompleteHidden" id="administradorAutocompleteType">
                            <f:param value="#{suggestionEntitiesDM.usuario}" name="type"></f:param>
                        </h:inputHidden>
                        <p:autoComplete id="administradorAutocomplete"
                                        value="#{empresaDM.administradorSeleccionada}"
                                        completeMethod="#{suggestionEntitiesDM.suggestionList}"
                                        var="administrador" itemLabel="#{administrador.txtNombreUsuario}"
                                        forceSelection="true" 
                                        itemValue="#{administrador}" converter="entityConverter">
                            <p:ajax event="start" update="administradorAutocomplete" process="administradorAutocompleteType"/>


                        </p:autoComplete>
```

What I want is to send the type parameter in request so that I can get the value by using:

```
String type=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("type");
```

However I'm just geeting null when referencing the type String, I have even checked the request parameters using Firebug and effectively administradorAutocompleteType=autoCompleteHidden is passed but type=value is never posted. 
What I am doing wrong?, how can I pass additional request parameters when using the f:ajax JSF 2 tag?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for my answer, it was wrong for you. I should have tested it with p:autoComplete first myself. Back to the problem, are you targeting a Servlet 3.0 environment? I.e. your target environment supports the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments?

Comment: I'm using Jboss AS 7, think it is Servlet 3.0 since web.xml is not necessary, however I don't think I have included support for EL 2.2 in my pom, should I use the glassfish 2.2 dependency, or maybe there's a Jboss EL equivalent that could be better in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you don't need to. All JSP/Servlet containers already ships with EL bundled. Servlet 3.0 (Java EE 6) already bundles EL 2.2. Just mark EL 2.2 as "provided" if necessary. But OK, the capability of the target environment is now more clear. If I have time, I will experiment with it for you.

Comment: Wait, why exactly do you need to pass a bean property back to a method which is in the **same** bean `#{suggestionEntitiesDM}`? Why don't you just access it as local variable in the method? E.g. `this.usuario;` inside `suggestionList()` method? Didn't you oversimplify the code example?

Comment: Because I wanted to make a reusable method that would return a List of suggestion entities (Using the Pojo capabilities of p:autocomplete), however to achieve this I needed to know wich is the Entity class that I should query, that It's why Im sending that value to avoid hardcoding params like name="type" value="MyClassName" (Think and Enum would have been a better choice... but didn't knew exactly how to use them with EL) everywhere through the pages that could potentially implement autocomplete componente.

Comment: OK, so let's assume that you just want to pass an additional parameter from the view side on, regardless of where it originates.

Comment: Yes, depending on wich autocomplete component created the request.

Comment: Another approach could be sending the parameter inside the method using EL 2.2 capabilities as you mentioned before, it would be something likes this: completeMethod=#{suggestionEntitiesDM.suggestionList(query,suggestionEntitiesDM.usuario)}. But in that case how would I obtain the query parameter that is expected to receive the complete method in order to filter suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this PF forum topic](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1886), `<p:ajax>` is **not** supported in `<p:autoComplete>`. Also, passing additional arguments is not possible in `completeMethod`.

I think [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) is most suitable for your purpose. It generates a JS function which allows you to set a bean property. This JS function is in turn to be called by `onstart` attribute of `<p:autoComplete>`.

```
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete 
        value="#{bean.text}" 
        onstart="setType()"
        completeMethod="#{bean.complete}"
        >
    </p:autoComplete>
    <p:remoteCommand name="setType">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.type}" value="foo" />
    </p:remoteCommand>
</h:form>
```

with

```
private String text;
private String type;

public List<String> complete(String query) {
    System.out.println("type: " + type); // type: foo
    // ...
}
```

You can set `foo` with whatever value you want. It'll be available as `type` in the scope of the `complete()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to the problem, the trick was to use f:attribute as suggested in this link:

[f:param or f:attribute support on primefaces autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567002/fparam-or-fattribute-support-on-primefaces-autocomplete)

since f:param was not being sent in the request, and the complete method required a fixed parameter to work.

Comment: Oh right, that's also a way :) Completely forgot that related question.