# jsf - primefaces - Passing parameter to primefaces autocomplete

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've tried to follow the solution in [f:param or f:attribute support on primefaces autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567002/fparam-or-fattribute-support-on-primefaces-autocomplete) to pass a parameter to primefaces 3.3.1 autocomplete component with no success. If I iterates in the Map returns by UIComponent.getCurrentComponent().getAttributes, it doesn't contain the attribute name I set in the .xhtml file, so I get a null pointer when I try to get the attribute. Is there any changes in primefaces implementation after the solution above?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo with Glassfish 3.1.2 and Mojarra 2.0.9.

Part of my code

xhtml :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    template="WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

...

<p:autoComplete 
   id="sourceSubMemberLookup" value="#{transactionTransferBacking.sourceSubMember}"
   size="64"
   completeMethod="#{transactionTransferBacking.completeSourceOpSubMember}"
   var="smb" itemLabel="#{smb.displayText}" itemValue="#{smb}"
   converter="opSubMemberConverter"
   forceSelection="true" dropdown="true"
   required="true" rendered="#{loggedInUser.subMemberType eq 1}" >
       <f:attribute name="attrSourceMemberId" value="#{transactionTransferBacking.sourceMember.Id">
</p:autoComplete>

...

</ui:composition>
```

java :

```
package com.mysoft.backing;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.Flash;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TransactionTransferBacking implements Serializable {

...

public List<OpSubMember> completeSourceOpSubMember(String query) {
    List<OpSubMember> members=null;

    //Retrieve list of submembers based on partial user input (autocomplete)
    //Based on loggedInUser own member's memberId

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context==null) this.getLogger().debug("completeSourceOpSubMeber: faces is null");

    UIComponent current = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context);

    this.getLogger().debug("completeSourceOpSubMember: currentComponent="+current.getId());

    //Map<Object, Object> attrMap = context.getAttributes();
    Map<String, Object> attrMap = current.getAttributes();

    for (Map.Entry entry : attrMap.entrySet()) {
        this.getLogger().debug("completeSourceOpSubMember: attrMap.Key="+entry.getKey());
    }

    int memberId = (int) attrMap.get("attrSourceMemberId");

    this.getLogger().debug("completeSourceOpSubMember: MemberId from attribute = "+memberId);


            ...

    return members;
}
}
```

The log correctly print the current component name as the desired AutoComplete, but the problem is "attrSourceMemberId" is not in the "attrMap" Map, as printed in the log.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Can you paste your code please (xhtml AND controller code)

Comment: I've updated my question with code parts and environment information, hope those clarify my problem. Thanks.